# Passing value to shorthand if result in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, conditional-operator

I'm trying to load all my tasks with all the related comments for that task.
What I have:

```
<p>{{count($task->comments) > 0 ? 'more' : '0'}} comments</p>
```

I want to display the count of comments if the statement turns out to be true.
So `'more'` -> `{{count($task->comments)}}`

If I do something like this:

```
 <p>{{count($task->comments) > 0 ? {{count($task->comments)}} : '0'}} comments</p>
```

I get the error: `syntax error, unexpected '{'` , how do I format this properly?

Comment: Where is your error?

Comment: edited my question

Comment: The problem is that your are using `php` and `javascript` in the same line without any precaution. Let me add a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't need any JavaScript help, you can do what you want with this:

```
<HTML>
   <p> <?php echo count($task->comments); ?> comments</p>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not echo using ternary operator. I suggest you try a different approach:

```
    <p>@php if(count($task->comments) > 0){
                echo 'more';
            }
            else{
                echo '0';
           }@endphp 

comments</p>
```

Actually you echoing your part using php and applying the "logic" there and the rest remain the same.